# Calculate $\lim_{x\to\pi/2}\frac{\sin(\cos(x))}{2x-\pi}$

Tags: calculus

> $$\lim_{x\to\pi/2}\frac{\sin(\cos(x))}{2x-\pi}$$

I already know that I should change the variable $x$ by $t = x-\pi/2$ but the problem is the $\cos x$ inside the $\sin$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. First of all try to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your question. Further show the process you have done so far :)

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

After making $t = \frac{\pi}{2}-x$, then $\sin ( \cos x ) = \sin ( \cos ( \pi/2 - t ) ) = \sin ( \sin t)$ Thus, limit becomes

$$ \frac{1}{-2} \lim_{t \to 0 } \frac{ \sin ( sin t ) }{t} $$

which is solved again by writing

$$ \frac{1}{-2} \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{ \sin ( \sin t ) }{\sin t} \cdot \frac{ \sin t }{t } $$

now, complete the problem (remember $\lim_{\alpha \to 0} \frac{ \sin \alpha}{\alpha} = 1 $)

Comment: you have $-2t$ in the denominator.